# jQuery UI animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to jQuery and am having some difficulty getting the result I'm after.

I have an image in a div that I would like to animate on hovering over it as in this example. http://thewebsitedeveloper.co.nz/thinkRedTest/pattonNz/optionOne.html

This works fine but I would prefer that the image didn't bounce continually. I would just like the image to move up up and stay in a raised position until the mouse leaves the containing div.

This is the script that's animating it at present:

```
$('.gHover').hover(function ()
{
    $(this).effect("bounce", { distance: 3, times:1 }, 900);
});
```

Comment: [`.effect()` is a jQuery UI method](http://jqueryui.com/effect/).  Updated title & tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event instead of `hover`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".boxx").mouseover(function(){       
     
      $(this).stop().animate({bottom:'5px'},"fast");
      
    });
  
  
  $(".boxx").mouseout(function(){       
    
      $(this).stop().animate({bottom:'0px'},"fast");
      
    });
  });

Comment: That reply got away from me. I did manage to come up with a solution using .animate, but it is a bit long winded compare the the mouseenter solution   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".boxx").mouseover(function(){       
     
      $(this).stop().animate({bottom:'5px'},"fast");
      
    });
  
  
  $(".boxx").mouseout(function(){       
     
      $(this).stop().animate({bottom:'0px'},"fast");
      
    });
  
  });

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.gHover').hover(function() {
  $(this)
    .css('position', 'relative')
    .stop(true, false)
    .animate({ top: '-10px' }, 400);
}, function() {
  $(this)
    .stop(true, false)
    .animate({ top: 0 }, 400);
});
```

This can also be achieved with CSS though which would be better to use for modern browsers that support transitions. You can then fallback to the above JS for those that don't. Examples of both here:

http://jsbin.com/omofis/2/edit